# Failed to execute job due to unexpected runtime exception with JDBC on Apache Ignite

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I'm getting the following error when running a query on one of ignite cluster servers, I'm using JDBC to connect to ignite.

the query:

```
public Connection connection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        // Register JDBC driver.
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver");

        // Opening a connection in the streaming mode and time based flushing set.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite://172.16.60.69:11211/");
        return conn;
    }


    public void query() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        Connection dbConnection= connection();
        System.out.println("Connection successful");

        String selectTableSQL = "select * from tableName limit 10";
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("statement created");

        System.out.println("Executing query...");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
        System.out.println("Query executed");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String userid = rs.getString(0);
            String username = rs.getString(1);  
            System.out.println(userid);
            System.out.println(username);

        }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Failed to execute job due to unexpected runtime exception [jobId=c8a9f954361-04b07e2b-bfb9-4421-b310-eae03e36ac58, ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.jdbc.GridCacheQueryJdbcTask, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1525866907994, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@63961c42, clsLdrId=14541c44361-0a306a0b-24ea-4173-905a-27dda62f72ba, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.jdbc.GridCacheQueryJdbcTask, sesId=b8a9f954361-04b07e2b-bfb9-4421-b310-eae03e36ac58, startTime=1525885528956, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=04b07e2b-bfb9-4421-b310-eae03e36ac58, clsLdr=org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@63961c42, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=false, subjId=04b07e2b-bfb9-4421-b310-eae03e36ac58, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=679771341]], execName=null], jobId=c8a9f954361-04b07e2b-bfb9-4421-b310-eae03e36ac58]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.jdbc.GridCacheQueryJdbcTask.reduce(GridCacheQueryJdbcTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.jdbc.GridCacheQueryJdbcTask.reduce(GridCacheQueryJdbcTask.java:65)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$6.call(GridTaskWorker.java:1113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.reduce(GridTaskWorker.java:1111)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:938)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:1060)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1285)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:802)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there anyway to get the root cause of this error? The error message doesn't help very much.

Comment: Can you look in the server nodes' logs, see if there are any exceptions here? If there's an erorr in one of your statements, it would be there unfortunately, not always reported back properly to the client.

Comment: Are you sure that is the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Yes that is the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @GherbiHicham The actual failure happened on the server node. Can you look into the server logs and past the error here, including the stacktrace?